# Does pdfTex produce warnings when it doesn't find the word hyphenation pattern?

Tags: pdftex, babel, hyphenation, warnings, debugging

In my document I use `babel` package and load several languages for correct hyphenation.

```
\usepackage[icelandic, latin, czech]{babel}
```

I add manually words that `babel` package doesn't know.

```
\begin{hyphenrules}{icelandic}
\hyphenation{
  pla-tó-nskt
}
\end{hyphenrules}
```

I wonder if I can find in `log` file warnings when the `pdfTex` using `babel` package tries to hyphenate word that it actually does not know. That would help me in adding the words into hyphenate rules.

Comment: The `babel` package provides hyphenation patterns for many languages and makes it straightforward to provide new hyphenation exceptions. However, it doesn't perform any hyphenation operations. It's the TeX engine you're using -- likely pdfTeX, XeTeX, or LuaTeX -- that does the hyphenation work.

Comment: Ok, thank you for exlanation. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX's hyphenation rules do not work on the basis of words, except for special exceptions specified in `\hyphenation`. The body of the hyphenation rules are generated by matching substrings of words in the document to a set of letter patterns that encourage or discourage hyphenation at that point.

So there is no sense really in which TeX does not "know" a word for hyphenation. Every word is matched against the patterns and that algorithm may specify zero or more hyphenation points. So the question is not whether TeX knows the word but whether the hyphenation points found by that algorithm match the hyphenation points in some published reference for that language, and that isn't something that TeX can answer itself.

Comment: Ok. I have realized I have written [similar question here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150785/8380). I am afraid I will have to manually proofread twocolumn 680 pages document using three different hyphenation patterns. :) Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @chejnik if it is worrying you you could use some external script to extract a sorted list of unique words and then use \showhyphens to get tex to show all the hyphenation points then you just need to proof read that without being distracted by the actual document and the subset of hyphenation points that are actually used.

Comment: @chejnik It is not necessary for tex to find all the allowed hyphenation points: most words do not come near the end of a line anyway. It only has to find enough points to avoid under or over full lines and it _does_ warn you about those. So if your book sets with no under/overfull box warnings then the hyphenation is good enough, if it does have warnings you just need to check the words around the bad break to see if additional hyphenation points help.

Comment: Firstly: that way I need to proof read all words found in the document - that is far far more than actually needed. Secondly: at least my pdfTex is capable of hyphenating words wrongly to avoid under/overfull box. So in reality it does not warn me. I post a link to [list of words](https://github.com/chejnik/LaTex-ICSS/blob/master/hyphen.tex) I have already found that were wrongly hyphenated.

Comment: An alternative approach, which will work in many documents, is to extract the text with `pdftotext -layout` and then search for lines ending with -  with a script (I use Python). Far from perfect, but it helps a lot.