combining ragged2e and mdframed
Minimal example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[experiment]
Cubum autem in duos cubos, aut quadratoquadratum in duos quadratoquadratos,
et generaliter nullam in infinitum ultra quadratum potestatem in duos
eiusdem nominis fas est dividere cuius rei demonstrationem mirabilem sane detexi.
Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet.
\end{definition}

\end{document}

gives me this:

What seems to be happening is that ragged2e, as well as allowing hyphenation in ragged-right environments, takes the liberty of sometimes going slightly over the allotted width when it thinks that makes for a better line. (It doesn't just happen with artificially long words, it happens in normal English text too, which prompted the question.)
How do I turn this off? The behavior I want is

No line may be longer than the maximum, under any circumstances.
Hyphenate as much as you like to improve the flow of text without breaking 1.
Make lines as short as necessary to achieve 1.

Interestingly, one of the three hyphenated lines here does meet that criteria.
Credit for the original text goes to Pierre de Fermat, who seems to also have had a problem with his margins. :)

Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried to help LaTeX by adding hypenation-signs in the problematic words or adding hypenation command in the preamble?

Do I really have to do that by hand? It seems like that way, every time I change a paragraph, I'd have to go back and see if any new words were breaking in the wrong place and fix that again.

Hyphenation rules are language dependent.  IIRC Babel for he appropriate language will help, but scientific words are often on their own.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150785/can-i-proofread-babel-hyphenation-rules-for-a-specific-language?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C82.2569

Ah, I see what you mean, but simple English words also sometimes extend over the boundary. The text I put in the example is not from the original document I'm trying to fix, it's just an example.

mdframed resets some margins in the environment and basically switches back to justifying. But it doesn't switch back the \spaceskip that ragged2e has changed and that means that TeX no longer finds good linebreaks as it can't stretch the spaces.
If you want raggedright everywhere you can try something like this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv{definition}{Definition}
\makeatletter\AddToHook{cmd/mdf@lrbox/after}{\RaggedRight}\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{definition}[experiment] 
Cubum autem in duos cubos, aut quadratoquadratum in duos quadratoquadratos,
et generaliter nullam in infinitum ultra quadratum potestatem in duos
eiusdem nominis fas est dividere cuius rei demonstrationem mirabilem sane detexi.
Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet.
\end{definition}

\end{document}


Generally I would recommend to drop mdframed which is unmaintained since around 10 years and to use tcolorbox instead.

Ok, I've spent an hour trying tcolorbox, and I want to cry ... how can I just make a simple 1px black border, no colors or shading? Another question suggests using the empty style but that causes my TeX to complain the key doesn't exist.

\begin{tcolorbox}[frame hidden,interior hidden,sharp corners,enhanced,borderline ={0.4pt}{0pt}{black}]  (requires \tcbuselibrary{skins}).

I'm accepting this answer as I've got it to work with your help now. I'm afraid my brain isn't built for being able to find something like this out on my own, even after carefully reading the reference manual (tcolorbox.pdf).

it doesn't harm to ask, the tcolorbox manual is long and as long as you make a nice MWE there will always be someone to help you out with some details.
